# PHP Laravel find a difference between 2 Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to find the difference between 2 value which I obtain from Query builder. The value obtain must within the right campus and month. I want to find the previous date value, current date value and next date value. After that, find the difference current value - previous value (name it as usage). The problem is, when I foreach the query builder, it only display 1 value instead of 2 for each query. Please help me.

```
$metercurr = DB::table('smt_meter_reading')
                       ->join('smt_smart_meter', 'smt_meter_reading.smt_smart_meter_id', '=', 'smt_smart_meter.id')
                       ->select(DB::raw('SUM(actual_generation) as total1', 'smt_meter_reading.id', 'smt_smart_meter.serial_number'))
                       ->whereBetween('read_time',[$currDate, $nextDate])
                       ->where('smt_smart_meter.campus_id', $bill->campus_id)
                       ->groupBy('smt_meter_reading.smt_smart_meter_id')
                       ->get();
    
$meterprev = DB::table('smt_meter_reading')
                       ->join('smt_smart_meter', 'smt_meter_reading.smt_smart_meter_id', '=', 'smt_smart_meter.id')
                       ->select(DB::raw('SUM(actual_generation) as total2', 'smt_smart_meter.serial_number'))
                       ->whereBetween('read_time',[$prevDate, $currDate])
                       ->where('smt_smart_meter.campus_id', $bill->campus_id)
                       ->groupBy('smt_meter_reading.smt_smart_meter_id')
                       ->get();
    
$metername = DB::table('smt_meter_reading')
                       ->join('smt_smart_meter', 'smt_meter_reading.smt_smart_meter_id', '=', 'smt_smart_meter.id')
                       ->select('smt_smart_meter.serial_number')
                       ->where('smt_smart_meter.campus_id', $bill->campus_id)
                       ->get();
    
$previous = 0;
$current = 0;
$usage = 0;
$serialno;

foreach ($meterprev as $data) {
    $previous = $data->total2;
}

foreach ($metercurr as $data) { 
    $current = $data->total1;
 }

foreach ($metername as $data) {
    $serialno = $data->serial_number;
}
    
$usage = $current - $previous;
```

Comment: Are you expecting there to be multiple readings returned in the ```$metercurr``` and ```$meterprev``` for unique ```smt_smart_meter_id``` values? Or are you expecting just one?

Comment: I am expecting multiple values. Supposedly, when I dd the both $metercurr & $meterprev, both have 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either nest your `foreach` statements with something to the effect of:

```
$usages = [];
foreach ($meterprev as $prevdata) {
    foreach ($metercurr as $currdata) {
        if ($prevdata->serial_number == $currdata->serial_number) {
            $usages = ($prevdata->total2 - $currdata->total1);
        }
    }
}
```

or just do a raw query with something like:

```
$sqlQuery = "

Select (second.total - first.total) as 'usage'
(
SELECT 
    'SUM(actual_generation) as total', 'smt_smart_meter.serial_number'
FROM 
    smt_meter_reading
JOIN 
    smt_smart_meter ON smt_smart_meter.id = smt_meter_reading.smt_smart_meter_id
WHERE 
    smt_smart_meter.campus_id = $campus_id AND
    read_time BETWEEN CAST($prevdate AS DATE) AND CAST($currdate AS DATE)
GROUP BY
    smt_meter_reading.smt_smart_meter_id
) as first,
(
    SELECT 
    'SUM(actual_generation) as total', 'smt_smart_meter.serial_number'
FROM 
    smt_meter_reading
JOIN 
    smt_smart_meter ON smt_smart_meter.id = smt_meter_reading.smt_smart_meter_id
WHERE 
    smt_smart_meter.campus_id = $campus_id AND
    read_time BETWEEN CAST($prevdate AS DATE) AND CAST($currdate AS DATE)
GROUP BY
    smt_meter_reading.smt_smart_meter_id
) as second
WHERE
    first.smt_smart_meter.serial_number = second.smt_smart_meter.serial_number
";

$result = DB::select(DB::raw($sqlQuery));
```

This should give you an array of usages. This could probably be done more efficiently or with eloquent but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: I have tried the first solution, but there is error Undefined property: stdClass:: $smt_smart_meter_id

Comment: My solutions don't reference that so I am not sure -  you will have to debug. Perhaps try the second solution.

Comment: The final output will look like this
The final output should be like this:-

Serial number     |   Previous reading  |  Current reading |      usage
AAA1234567       |   2345.3            | 6643.3           | 4298.0
ASZD642130       |  1234.5             | 2131.2           | 896.7

Comment: Were you able to get the calculated value that you were trying to get?

Comment: Yes, but, the things is it only produce one result instead of two. And, how can I display it in blade?

total 1 : 1234.5
total 1 : 2334.2

total 2 :953.3
total 2 :2121.1

usage : 281.3

Formula, usage = total 1 - total 2

It only produce 1 results instead of 2

Comment: Since i need to display total1 & total 2 in blade, i try to merge both collection. But when displaying in blade using foreach {{$data->total1}}, i got an error 'undefined property stdClass = $total1.